# Sequential vs simultaneous file loading in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm developing a data visualization for which I need to load multiple JSON files from my file system and get another one from a webservice. I'm currently using the sequential approach (json files are being loaded with d3.js):

```
d3.json('Cata_provincias.geojson', function(contents){
    provincias_json = contents
    d3.json('Cata_girona.geojson', function(contents_girona){
        girona_json = contents_girona
        d3.json('Cata_barcelona.geojson', function(contents_barcelona){
            barcelona_json = contents_barcelona
            d3.json('Cata_tarragona.geojson', function(contents_tarragona){
                tarragona_json = contents_tarragona
                d3.json('Cata_lleida.geojson', function(contents_lleida){
                    lleida_json = contents_lleida
                    init()
                })
            })
        })
    })
})
```

My question is, would I get a better load time if I fetch all the files simultaneously? Is this the best approach?

**Edit:** I know how to do the simultaneous load. What I want to know is if it will speed the initial load and wheter it is a good practice.

Comment: To load many files, use [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call all json functions in order, and have each callback trigger the init function. The init function would then have to count how many calls have been made and only once the count reaches the correct value, do the actual initialization.

```
d3.json('Cata_provincias.geojson', function(contents){
    provincias_json = contents
    init()
})
d3.json('Cata_girona.geojson', function(contents_girona){
    girona_json = contents_girona
    init()
})
d3.json('Cata_barcelona.geojson', function(contents_barcelona){
    barcelona_json = contents_barcelona
    init()
})
d3.json('Cata_tarragona.geojson', function(contents_tarragona){
    tarragona_json = contents_tarragona
    init()
})
d3.json('Cata_lleida.geojson', function(contents_lleida){
    lleida_json = contents_lleida
    init()
})

var count = 0
function init() {
    if(++count < 5)
        return

    // Do actual initialization here 
}
```

Comment: I know how to do the simultaneous load. What I want to know is if it will speed the load and if it's a good practice.

Comment: And my answer shows a ***better*** approach (you asked if yours is the best, right?), and it *will* speed up loading because you'll have multiple concurrent requests being processed in parallel.

Comment: I tested it and the simultaneous approach does indeed speed up the loading. Tough it's not exactly what I asked this answer and its comments contain all the info other users might need. I'm accepting it.